# Trying to dump a file - Python

Tags: python, json, web

I'm trying to dump a web to a file to get the data I need for a project.
The web looks like this.
[image: Image1]

And the resulting file is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>        
        <!--Meta tags-->  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1280"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=0.8"/>

        <!--Stylesheets--> 
        <link href="../../../css/layout.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />

        <!--Janitza Library-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../lib/jquery.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../lib/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../lib/lib_full_min.js" ></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../lib/app.js" ></script>
        
        <!--Other Javascripts-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../../javascripts/menu.js" ></script>
        
        <!--Javascripts - Language-->   
        <script>
            var vars = null;
            var data = null;
            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: "../../../../json.do?_LANGUAGE",
                async: false,
                data: data,
                success: function(data){
                    vars = data;
                }
              });
            var language = vars["_LANGUAGE"][0];
            var systime = new Date().getTime();
            document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../egg.js?' + systime + '"></sc' + 'ript>');
            document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../lang/info.js?' + systime + '"></sc' + 'ript>');
            document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../lang/' + language + '.js?' + systime + '" encoding="utf-8" ></sc' + 'ript>');
            document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="../../../lang/en.js?' + systime + '" encoding="utf-8" ></sc' + 'ript>');
            
            CurrentLanguage = language.toLowerCase();
            CurrentChallenge = "";         
            
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                InsertsEggs();
              });     
        </script>
        
        <!--Title-->  
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div id="top-bar">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="logo"></div>
                    <div class="devicetype"></div>
                    <div id="languagebox">
                        <ul id="languageselector">
                            <!-- Ausgabe der Flaggen fuer die Sprachauswahl -->
                            <LangSelect></LangSelect>
                            <!-- ENDE Sprachauswahl -->
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--End .wrapper--> 
            </div>
            <!--End top-bar--> 
            <div id="menu-bar">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div id="navigationbar">
                        <ul id="navigation">

                        </ul>        
                    </div>

                </div>
                <!--End .wrapper--> 
            </div>
            <!--End menu-bar--> 

            <div id="content">
                <div class="wrapper">


    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/functions.js" ></script>
    
    <div class="full-width-frame" >

        <div class="top">

            <span class="trans">menu.soverview</span>

        </div>

        <div class="center">

            <div class="whitebar">
                <div class="white-one">
                    <div class="white-img"><img src="../layout/devicename.png"></div>
                    <div class="white-text"><span class="trans">soverview.device</span></div>
                    <div class="white-value"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="white-two">
                    <div class="white-img"><img src="../layout/time.png"></div>
                    <div class="white-text"><span class="trans">soverview.time</span></div>
                    <div class="white-value" id="time">
                        <script>
                            hideL4();
                            time();
                            setInterval(function(){
                                hideL4();
                                time();
                            }, 3000);
                            
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="white-three">
                    <div class="white-img"><img src="../layout/freq.png"></div>
                    <div class="white-text"><span class="trans">soverview.freq</span></div>
                    <div class="white-value"><script>document.write(sysvar("_FREQ", AUTOUPDATE, 2));</script></div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <table style="width: 1100px; margin: 0 auto">
                <tr>
                    <td VALIGN="top">
                        <table class="showtable" >
                            <tr>
                                <th><span class="trans">soverview.phase</span></th>
                                <th><span class="trans">soverview.uvll</span></th>
                                <th><span class="trans">soverview.uvln</span></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>L1/L2</br>L1/N</td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_ULL[0]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_ULN[0]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>L2/L3</br>L2/N</td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_ULL[1]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_ULN[1]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>L3/L1</br>L3/N</td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_ULL[2]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_ULN[2]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>L4/N</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_ULN[3]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td VALIGN="top" align="center">
                        <table class="showtable" >
                            <tr>
                                <th><span class="trans">soverview.phase</span></th>
                                <th><span class="trans">kW</span></th>
                                <th><span class="trans">kWh</span></th>
                                <th><span class="trans">kvar</span></th>
                                <th><span class="trans">kvarh</span></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="trans">L1</span></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_PLN[0]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, ["k"], HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_WH[0]", AUTOUPDATE, 0, ["k"], HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_QLN[0]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, ["k"],  HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_QH[0]", AUTOUPDATE, 0, ["k"],  HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="trans">L2</span></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_PLN[1]", AUTOUPDATE, ["k"], 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_WH[1]", AUTOUPDATE, 0, ["k"], HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_QLN[1]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, ["k"],  HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_QH[1]", AUTOUPDATE, 0, ["k"],  HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="trans">L3</span></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_PLN[2]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, ["k"], HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_WH[2]", AUTOUPDATE, 0, ["k"], HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_QLN[2]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, ["k"],  HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_QH[2]", AUTOUPDATE, 0, ["k"],  HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="trans">L4</span></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_PLN[3]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, ["k"], HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_WH[3]", AUTOUPDATE, 0, ["k"], HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_QLN[3]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, ["k"],  HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_QH[3]", AUTOUPDATE, 0, ["k"],  HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="trans">L1..L3</span></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_P_SUM3", AUTOUPDATE, 2, ["k"], HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_WH[4]", AUTOUPDATE, 0, ["k"], HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_Q_SUM3", AUTOUPDATE, 2, ["k"],  HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_QH[4]", AUTOUPDATE, 0, ["k"],  HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="trans">L1..L4</span></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_P_SUM", AUTOUPDATE, 2, ["k"], HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_WH[5]", AUTOUPDATE, 0, ["k"], HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_Q_SUM", AUTOUPDATE, 2, ["k"],  HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_QH[5]", AUTOUPDATE, 0, ["k"],  HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </td>
                    <td VALIGN="top" align="right">
                        <table class="showtable" >
                            <tr>
                                <th><span class="trans">soverview.phase</span></th>
                                <th><span class="trans">IinA</span></th>
                                <th><span class="trans">cos-phi</span></th>
                                <th><span class="trans">THD-U</span></th>
                                <th><span class="trans">THD-I</span></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="trans">L1</span></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_ILN[0]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_COS_PHI[0]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_THD_ULN[0]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_THD_IL[0]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="trans">L2</span></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_ILN[1]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_COS_PHI[1]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_THD_ULN[1]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_THD_IL[1]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="trans">L3</span></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_ILN[2]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_COS_PHI[2]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_THD_ULN[2]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_THD_IL[2]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="trans">L4</span></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_ILN[3]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_COS_PHI[3]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_THD_ULN[3]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_THD_IL[3]", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="trans">L1..L3</span></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_I_SUM3", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_COS_SUM3", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="trans">L1..L4</span></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_I_SUM", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td><script>document.write(sysvar("_COS_SUM", AUTOUPDATE, 2, HIDEUNIT));</script></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>

        <div class="bottom"></div>

    </div>

    <!--End full-width-frame--> 

    
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--End content--> 

            <div id="footer-bar">
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="footdevice"></div>
                </div>
                <!--End .wrapper--> 
            </div>
            <!--End footer-bar--> 
        </div>
        <!--End main--> 
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

That is, a strange script comes out where there should be the digits that appear in the image.

And the code I use to import the web is:

```
curl http://www.phl.org/cgi-bin/fidsarrival.pl -o "arrival.txt"
```

I need to get the digits out so I can take them out and insert them somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to scrape a webpage.

The issue you are facing is that the webpage has dynamic content. curl just fetches the webpage html as on the server but when you open the page in a browser, the JavaScript on the page is executed and fetches some JSON data from the server and then updates the webpage.

Check out Selenium for dynamic pages. There are some other web scraping tools/frameworks out there that might help you.